# How to add to a queue via references without changing references accidently?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a series of way points that are classes. They inherit mono behaviours so they cannot be structs, plus they have behaviours depending on the derived type of way point.

I add each waypoint an AI visits to the queue so they don't wander back to a previous visited one.

How ever, if i now change the AI's `CurrentWaypoint` to the next one he arrives at, this changes the one in the queue. So i end up with a queue of all the same waypoint reference.

How can i prevent this but still be able to check if `CurrentWaypoint` exists in the queue via reference checks ? I believe if i just use a copy then the reference checks will fail so thats not good either.

My two methods are:

```
private bool HasVisited(Waypoint wp)
{
    if (_previousVisits.Contains(wp))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private void AddVisited(Waypoint wp)
{
    // we only need the last 2 wp's visited
    if (_previousConnections.Count > 1)
    {
        _previousConnections.Dequeue();
    }
    _previousVisits.Enqueue(wp);
}
```

Whats the best solution to this problem ?

Comment: How about cloning the Waypoint?

Comment: Would that still equal the same thing for the `HasVisited` method? Also isn't that generally a bad idea?

Comment: You would then need to override the Equals and GetHashCode method. If you do not have access to the Waypoint class, then just wrap it in your own new WaypointWrapper class. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so, I would build a wrapper class around Waypoint to provide my own comparison such as:

```
public class WaypointWrapper
{
    private readonly Vector3D _waypointPosition;

    public WaypointWrapper(Waypoint waypoint)
    {
          /* Assuming the Waypoint class has a position property that is a Vector3D struct */
          _waypointPosition = waypoint.position;
    }

    public override Equals(object obj)
    {
         var otherWaypointWrapper  = obj as WaypointWrapper;

         if(otherWaypointWrapper == null)
             return false;

         return otherWaypointWrapper._waypointPosition.Equals(_waypointPosition);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
         return _waypointPosition.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```